# Clearing HTML content with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to hide an portion of HTML that I've included in my index.html. What happens right now is when I search for a user a table, along with contents, gets rendered on the page. The behavior that I want is when "Clear" is pressed that included HTML table, along with its contents, is removed. Right now the table will only show if the $scope.user has a value and that check is done with ng-if. When I click the "Clear" button I set $scope.user to "false" which I thought would remove the include. I've also tried adding it to the table DOM element but that doesn't work either. What am I not getting? I'm sure it's a fairly simple fix for someone who knows more about Angular.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="githubViewer">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>

  <div>{{ error }}</div>
  <form name="searchUser" ng-submit="search(username)">
    <input type="search" required placeholder="Username..." ng-model="username" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    <button ng-click="clearSearch()">Clear</button>
  </form>

  <div ng-include="'userDetails.html'" ng-if="user"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("githubViewer", []);

  var MainController = function($scope, $http) {

    var onUserComplete = function(response) {
      $scope.user = response.data;
      $http.get($scope.user.repos_url)
        .then(onRepos, onError);
    };

    var onRepos = function(response) {
      $scope.repos = response.data;
    }

    var onError = function(reason) {
      $scope.error = "Could not fetch the data";
    }

    $scope.search = function(username) {
      $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
        .then(onUserComplete, onError);
    }

    $scope.clearSearch = function() {
      return ($scope.user = false);
    }

    $scope.message = "Github Viewer";
    $scope.repoSortOrder = "+name";
  };


  app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$http", MainController])

}());
```

userDetail.html

```
<div>
  <h2>{{ user.name }}</h2>
  <img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ user.gravatar_id }}" />
  <h2>User Repositories</h2>
  Order By:
  <select ng-model="repoSortOrder">
    <option value="+name">Name</option>
    <option value="-stargazers_count">Stars</option>
    <option value="+language">Language</option>
  </select>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Repository Name</th>
        <th>Stars</th>
        <th>Language</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos | orderBy:repoSortOrder">
        <td><a href="{{ repo.html_url }}">{{ repo.name }}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ repo.stargazers_count | number }}</td>
        <td>{{ repo.language }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. The problem was that the

`<button ng-click="clearSearch()">Clear</button>`

was in the `<form>` so when I clicked the "Clear" button the Search function was being executed again. I noticed this via the Chrome console since I had XHR requests turned on...when I clicked "Clear" another GET was being executed.

I moved the button outside of the `<form>` and the functionality works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

clearSearch() should be setting the value of $scope.user instead of returning a value:

```
$scope.clearSearch = function() {
  $scope.user = false;
}
```

Comment: I tried that before asking for help and it seemed to show the same behaviour of not removing the content.